# Movement on Labyrinth with Best First Search

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, heuristics, searching

I have the following labyrinth where `R` is the robot(the parent node), red blocks are the obstacles where the `R` cannot move and `GOAL` is the node where we want the robot to go. Every node should be written in this form `R(1,2,4)`, `1` is the row, `2` is the column and `4` is the distance from the current node to the goal node `GOAL`.

[image]

I am in a position where the solution tree looks like this

[image]

Now, I don't know which node should I select `C` or `D` ? Both of them have the same distance to the goal.

Comment: If they both have the same distance to goal then it will not matter which one you take. Unless there is some alternative tie breaker, choosing either one is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doens't matter which one you take, because they both have exactly the same value. Which one actually gets taken will depend on unimportant details of the implementation, such as the order the nodes were added to the tree.